# Arrange array in alternate negative & positive numbers using Javascript/ES

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to arrange an array

```js
[1,4,7,6,8,-1,-4,-5,8]
```

like

```js
[-1,1,-4,4,-5,7,6,8,8]
```

How can I do this using JavaScript ? I thought of using the map function making positive number array and negative number array and merge them one-by-one. But I having trouble merging them.

```js
let arr = [1,4,7,6,8,-1,-4,-5,8];

let positiveArr = arr.map((a) => a >= 0);
let negativeArr = arr.map((a) => a < 0);

final_arr = negativeArr.map(function(v,i) { return [v, positiveArr[i]]; });
console.log(final_arr)
```

Comment: Can you share what have you done till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter all the positive numbers into an array and all the negative numbers into an array. Afterward, alternately push negative and positive numbers into a new array.

```js
const arr = [-1,1,-4,4,-5,7,6,8,8];
const positive = arr.filter(x=>x>=0);
const negative = arr.filter(x=>x<0);
const res = [];
for(let i = 0, j = 0; i < positive.length || j < negative.length; i++, j++){
  if(j < negative.length) res.push(negative[i]);
  if(i < positive.length) res.push(positive[i]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your solution works fine on the give array but isn't maintaining order on different arrays like [-5, -2, 5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 8, 0, -8]

Comment: @SAMUEL How does it not maintain order? What is the expected output there? It gives `[0, 1, -2, 2, 4, -5, 5, 7, -8, 8]` for me.

Comment: the expected output should be [-5, 5, -2, 2, -8, 4, 7, 1, 8, 0]

Comment: @SAMUEL Could you explain your criteria for sorting? I don't see why that is the expected output.

Comment: you just need to pick the first  -ve number and place it at the begining and then the next +ve number and again next occuring -ve number and so on.. if -ve no.s run out append all the positive numbers

Comment: I didn't need the .sort() function so I removed it and I got my expected output. Thanks a ton

Comment: @SAMUEL No problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```js
const arr = [1,4,7,6,8,-1,-4,-5,8]
arr.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(b) - Math.abs(a)).reverse()
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: the order of the negative numbers isn't maintained on different arrays like [-5, -2, 5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 8, 0, -8] the expected output => [-5, 5, -2, 2, -8, 4, 7, 1, 8, 0]